# Add string after the header rows for saving csv files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I would like to ask how do you add a string below the header in python when saving a data series with pandas? A certain program which needs to load this .txt requires this string in order to separate the data and the header. The code I have done to save the data is as follows.

```
Data = {'Title_Column1':Column1, 'Title_Column2':Column2}
Data = pd.DataFrame(Data) 
Data.to_csv("Data.txt", index=False, sep ='\t')
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
Title_Column1 Title_Column2
START_OF_DATA   
0.0000000     0.0000000
```

Comment: please provide `Column1` and `Column2`

Comment: Data.txt ? Why are you giving a txt

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a row with the string that you want after the first header row, if that works for you. However this method will insert a string value in the first cell of the first row like this -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...:   
   ...: dict = {'Name':['Martha', 'Tim', 'Rob', 'Georgia'],
   ...:         'Maths':[87, 91, 97, 95],
   ...:         'Science':[83, 99, 84, 76]
   ...:        }
   ...:   
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
   ...: 
   ...: df
Out[1]:
      Name  Maths  Science
0   Martha     87       83
1      Tim     91       99
2      Rob     97       84
3  Georgia     95       76

In [2]: df.loc[0] = ['Start_Of_Data', '', '']
   ...: df
Out[2]:
            Name Maths Science
0  Start_Of_Data
1            Tim    91      99
2            Rob    97      84
3        Georgia    95      76
```

Hope this helps!